# How to assign an image from URL to NSData by swift?

Tags: swift, nsdata

I am new to swift.

I have one code.   It encode a local image logo.png to NSData.

```
let testImage = NSData(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("logo", ofType: "png")!)
```

How to encode an image from a URL to NSData?

Comment: Is it a local resource URL or a  website image URL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-image-from-url/27712427#27712427

Comment: it is a website image URL.

Comment: Don't use that answer it would lock your app in case you lose your internet connection and there is no guarantee it will succeed

Comment: Use the async method NSURLSession

Answer (score 4):

Replace `myURL` with the required URL:

`let testImage = NSData(contentsOfURL: myURL)`

Comment: I tried, but testImage's value is not the same as the one I got from local filesystem.    Even the local image and the image on the website are the same files (just two copies).

Comment: I use:  let url = NSURL(string: "http://www...c.om/logo.png")
        let testImage = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

Comment: @HZh forget about this mehod try reading the answer from the link I posted

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :-

```
var image: UIImage?

let imgURL = NSURL(string: "\(yourURL)")
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!)
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
     // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
     image = UIImage(data: data!)
  } else {
     image = UIImage(named: "JobPlaceholder") // if occurred an error put a placeholder image
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done in swift 3.3 and 4. But this will hang UI and result in jerk.

```
do {
      let imgData = try NSData(contentsOf: URL.init(string: "SomeUrl")!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
      let image = UIImage(data: imgData as Data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
          completionBlock(image)
   }
} catch {

}
```

You can also pass image url to dataTask method of URLSession and get data in response. This is best way to avoid jerk in UI. Like below

```
if let url = URL(string: "someUrl") {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
          let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
          let data = data, error == nil,
          let image = UIImage(data: data) else    {
                DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                    completionBlock(nil)
                }
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                completionBlock(image)
            }
          }.resume()
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

**This one is working in Swift 3.0** Replace the **contentsof:forcastURL** with **contentsOf: forecastURL! as URL**

```
     let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "http://photos.state.gov/libraries/media/788/images/90x90.gif")

    let testImage = NSData (contentsOf: forecastURL! as URL)

    print("data",testImage!)

    let image = UIImage(data: testImage! as Data)
    print("imaGE :-",image!)
```